# codeigniter site_url() is not working

Tags: codeigniter

**controller**

```
<?php

class RestaurantMain extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('homePage.php');
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('assets/styles/res.css'); ?>">

</head>

<body>
    <p>this is restaurant</p>
</body>
</html>
```

there is no error msg but it is not working.here is the view source code,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:80/RestaurantManagementSystem/index.php/assets/styles/res.css">
```

Comment: try `base_url` instead

Comment: it also doesn't working

Comment: `but it is not working` is not sufficient here, always post what is expected output @user3840485

Comment: I guess `localhost` is the problem, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to have clear understanding of site_url() & base_url(). Whenever you are accessing the site related links like http://www.example.com/events/eventFrom/24102195 then you can give the link in this way

```
site_url('events/eventFrom/'.$date)
```

but if you are trying to get access of your website's directory specific contents like images/css/javascript etc. that time you need to use the base_url(). 
In your case link would be like:

```
href="<?php echo base_url('assets/styles/res.css')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

go through    aplication-> config->config.php and make changes like this in your config file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

then your site_url() and base_url() will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

check config.php in config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:80/RestaurantManagementSystem';
```

and your view to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/styles/res.css')?>" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to call your stylesheet?
Try this:

```
<link href="<?=style_url('assets/styles/res.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: there is no function called `style_url` in codeigniter unless you have created a helper post that code too